# create a template page for a post

Tags: custom-post-types, pages, page-template

i am new in wordpress and i am sorry for my english. 
May be my title is wrong. sorry for that.

My question is like that.

I have too many custom post types. I need some pages for a specific custom post type.

For example: I have musics, books and movies. I want to create a template for them like that;
http://example.com/book/a-book-name/author
http://example.com/movie/a-movie-name/director

How can I do that? Thank you for helping and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a rewrite tag and rules that capture anything after the post name:

```
function wpd_add_rewrites(){

    add_rewrite_tag( '%my_page%', '(.+)' );

    $post_types = array(
        'movie',
        'book',
        'album'
    );

    foreach( $post_types as $post_type ){
        add_rewrite_rule(
            '^' . $post_type . '/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?',
            'index.php?post_type=' . $post_type . '&name=$matches[1]&my_page=$matches[2]',
            'top'
        );
    }

}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_add_rewrites' );
```

Don't forget, you must flush rewrite rules after adding / changing them. You can do this quickly by just visiting the Settings > Permalinks page.

You can then check the value of `my_page` anywhere after the `wp` action:

```
echo get_query_var( 'my_page' );
```

Comment: It worked but now I need filter them. For example: if 'my_page' is 'author' or 'example' show my page else show 404 page. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, look. When you create the custom post. you must add this lines. If you see, you add .. 'supports' => array('page-attributes'... this option show a select in your post for choose the parent post.

```
register_post_type(
    'my_post_type',
    array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug'       => 'my_post_type',
            'with_front' => false,
        ),
        'supports' => array(
            'page-attributes' /* This will show the post parent field */,
            'title',
            'editor',
            'something-else',
        ),
        // Other arguments
    )
);
```

Comment: Ok, it finely work when i add a new post for book's author. but i already added informations for that post with using custom fields. so i dont need and i dont wanna add new post. you can think like comments. i want show comments on http://example.com/book/a-book/comments

Comment: I understand what you say, but I guess that's more complicated and would require a lot more code. I guess using the url passing variables could be an option. Sorry I can not be of more help.

Comment: Do you know how can I use the url passing variables in wordpress? Actually it can be help for me

Comment: Yes, easy.
In your file functions, you create de variable
`function add_custom_query_var( $vars ){
  $vars[] = "a";
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_custom_query_var' );`

you can call in other page with:

'$my_a = get_query_var( 'a' );'

you can use like this: http://example.com/movie/a-movie-name/?a=name_autor

Comment: thank i did. now i need to use add_rewrite_rule for SEO link so can you help me for that?